# Get author_id from mail_message in openERP

Tags: python, orm, odoo

I'm trying to get a field from openERPs mail_message model using python code which is executed in a `server action` (so its not a module where I can debug! I cannot even `print` in this state) (when a new eMail is being fetched) but I am unable to get anything useful from it.

Basicly when someone is throwing me a email, a new Task is created by openERP. But the newely created ticket is not connected to the user which send me the mail.

When a new email is fetched, this server action gets executed.

In a table called mail_message you can then find the email (+ author_id, + email, + res_id (which is the id of the created Task), therefore I'd like to fetch the author_id from that table.
(A query would look like this:
`SELECT author_id FROM mail_message WHERE type = 'email' AND res_id = '<Task.id>'`)

This is my current code

```
#Initialize object. That one points to the mail_message model.
mailMessage_obj = self.pool.get('mail.message')

#Created Id in project_task
myId = object.id

#browse whole object with that id
#message = mailMessage_obj.browse(cr,uid,[myId])

#Select field where 
messageIds = mailMessage_obj.search(cr,uid,[('type','=','email'),('res_id','=',myId)],context=context)

if messageIds:
    #messageRecord = mailMessage_obj.browse(cr,uid,[myId],context=context)
    #object.write({'partner_id':messageRecord.author_id.id})

    res = mailMessage_obj.read(messageIds, ['author_id'])
    partnerId = res[0]

    #Author id
    #partnerId = message[0]['author_id']
    #partnerId = message.author_id


    #res = [(r['id'], r['author_id']) for r in messageRecord]

    #partnerId = res

    #partnerId = 259866
    object.write({'partner_id':partnerId})
```

I dont know how to get my hands on the author_id properly. If I hardcode a ID and let it write to the database (last two lines) It'll work just fine, but I cant hardcode a users id. ;)

Could someone explain to me how its done correctly?
I dont know whether I should use .browse or .read or something else..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error on you python method.
you wrote :

```
res = mailMessage_obj.read(messageIds, ['author_id'])
partnerId = res[0]
```

But read() method returns here a list of dict (because messageIds is a list). Then, you have not specified the field you wanted to retrieve from **res**  variable, and finally, as author_id is a **many2one**, it returns something like this : (2, 'myusers').

You should have done :

```
res = mailMessage_obj.read(cr, uid, messageIds, ['author_id'])
partnerId = res[0]['author_id'][0]
```

Hope i helped you,

Greatings

Comment: I can test this on next wednesday. I'll come back to that later, just wanted to let you know. Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it.

Comment: It now throws a "TypeError: read() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)".

Comment: Yes i missed some arguments on the method, i edited my answer below :
res = mailMessage_obj.read(cr, uid, messageIds, ['author_id'])